# Deregister UINib from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is any way to deregister o dealloc a registered `UINib UITableViewCell`?

I have memory issues with a registered `UINib UITableViewCell`. When my UITableViewController pops from the screen, the `UINib UITableViewCell`s stills on memory.

How can I do the opposite of this:

```
 tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "LoadingTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "LoadingCellIdentifier")
```

Comment: The memory problem you encounter has nothing to do with registering a nib. Please post the full view controller code so we can figure out what is really wrong with it.

Comment: Memory deallocation is automatically handled with ARC. So the opposite of that is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UINib are cached by default

> Instances of the UINib class serve as object wrappers, or containers,
>   for Interface Builder nib files. A UINib object caches the contents of
>   a nib file in memory, ready for unarchiving and instantiation. When
>   your application needs to instantiate the contents of the nib file it
>   can do so without having to load the data from the nib file first,
>   improving performance. The UINib object can automatically release this
>   cached nib data to free up memory for your application under
>   low-memory conditions, reloading that data the next time your
>   application instantiates the nib.

And they are removed from cache automatically under low memory condition.
The registration is just an easy way to recall the cell that you need avoiding to put a lot of boilerplate code inside .`tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, there is no way to unregister and I'm pretty sure that there is no need to.

If you are experiencing memory issues, I'm sure you are handling a lot of images and of course that answer to your problem is on how you get rid of them.
Please post your code and tomorrow I can be more helpful.